# Warning message when calling a SOAP webservice

Tags: web-services, soap

I'm getting this warning message when trying to call a SOAP webservice

```
May 28, 2014 10:25:39 AM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter fixQuotesAroundSoapAction
INFO: Received WS-I BP non-conformant Unquoted SoapAction HTTP header: /performAction
```

Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code responsible for this warning,

```
/**
 *
 * @param con
 * @param codec
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 *         ExceptionHasMessage exception that contains particular fault message
 *         UnsupportedMediaException to indicate to send 415 error code
 */
private Packet decodePacket(@NotNull WSHTTPConnection con, @NotNull Codec codec) throws IOException {
    String ct = con.getRequestHeader("Content-Type");
    InputStream in = con.getInput();
    Packet packet = new Packet();
    packet.soapAction = fixQuotesAroundSoapAction(con.getRequestHeader("SOAPAction"));
    packet.wasTransportSecure = con.isSecure();
    packet.acceptableMimeTypes = con.getRequestHeader("Accept");
    packet.addSatellite(con);
    packet.transportBackChannel = new Oneway(con);
    packet.webServiceContextDelegate = con.getWebServiceContextDelegate();

    if (dump) {
        ByteArrayBuffer buf = new ByteArrayBuffer();
        buf.write(in);
        in.close();
        dump(buf, "HTTP request", con.getRequestHeaders());
        in = buf.newInputStream();
    }
    codec.decode(in, ct, packet);
    return packet;
}

/**
 * Some stacks may send non WS-I BP 1.2 conformant SoapAction.
 * Make sure SOAPAction is quoted as {@link Packet#soapAction} expectsa quoted soapAction value.
 *
 * @param soapAction SoapAction HTTP Header
 * @return
 */
private String fixQuotesAroundSoapAction(String soapAction) {
    if(soapAction != null && (!soapAction.startsWith("\"") || !soapAction.endsWith("\"")) ) {
        LOGGER.warning("Received WS-I BP non-conformant Unquoted SoapAction HTTP header: "+ soapAction);
        String fixedSoapAction = soapAction;
        if(!soapAction.startsWith("\""))
            fixedSoapAction = "\"" + fixedSoapAction;
        if(!soapAction.endsWith("\""))
            fixedSoapAction = fixedSoapAction + "\"";
        return fixedSoapAction;
    }
    return soapAction;
}
```

The SOAP Action consists of the namespace and the actual method needs to call.
Furthermore, the SOAP Action needs to be encapsulated in " " to work.
Below helper method can be used to generate SOAP Action:

```
public String getSoapAction(String method) {
    return "\"" + NAMESPACE + method + "\""; 
}
```

Hope this will answer your question.

Comment: Pardon me, but how do you know that this code is responsible for the warning received by the OP?